# Multiple Partial specialization and full specialization required <> after type definition

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

I'm using an C++ "event" class that allowed one or two arguments in the to be called delegates.

Lately I've added support for delegates that don't require arguments, however when I specialze the class to use no template arguments I'm still required to add **<>** afther the class definition.

Example usage with one/two arguments:

```
class Example 
{
public:
    event<int> SingleArgEvent;
    event<int, int> DoubleArgEvent;
};
```

And here the no argument example:

```
class Example 
{
public:
    event<> NoArgTest1; // compiles just fine
    event NoArgTest2;   // gives me C2955: 'event' : use of class template requires template argument list
};
```

As it works with the brackets, I don't see a reason why they should to be there.
Here's the class specialization code:

```
class null_typelist {};
/** event template **/
template <class Targ1 = null_typelist, class Targ2 = null_typelist>
class event : public event2_base<Targ1, Targ2>
{
};

template <class Targ>
class event<Targ, null_typelist> : public event1_base<Targ>
{
};

template <>
class event<null_typelist, null_typelist> : public event0_base
{
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call a function *foo* with no arguments you have to write `foo()` not just `foo`. That is exactly the same for template types. `event` is not a type, it is a "function" that takes types and return a type.
If you really want to avoid writing the brackets, you can still do something like:

```
typedef event<> event_;
```

Comment: The Idea was to have the same class name "event" no matter how much template arguments. With an typedef that goes away. I guess there's no workaround?

Answer (score 3):

Brackets are required because the C++ grammar says so.

In 14.2/1 (temp.names/1), < and > are not optional, while template-argument-list is. So event<> is a valid template-id while event is not due to lack of <>.

```
template-id:
           template-name  < template-argument-list opt >
```